# How to write to a specific offset, using a file handle

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm injecting a DLL into a process, retrieve a file handle.

Then I try to write using the [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) Winapi function. This works great, but if I want to write to a specific offset (adding the offset arg, instead of NULL),

```
_OVERLAPPED offset;
offset.Offset = 0xFFFFFFFF;
offset.OffsetHigh = 0xFFFFFFFF;
if (!WriteFile(hFile, &buffer, 9, &written,&offset)) {
    Debug(GetLastErrorStdStr());
}
```

then I get:

> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS 183 
>   Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Which makes me think I can't because the HANDLE has been created WITHOUT the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED. Could this be coming from something else ?

If this is indeed the cause of the error, is there a hacky workaround ?

Comment: Where's the code that opens the file? It's relevant to your question.

Comment: I don't have it, that's the tricky part ;) I'm injecting in another process, whose I don't have the source. So, can you remove the -1 ?

Comment: You're getting `hFile` from somewhere. Where and how specifically?

Comment: Just from x64_dbg, handles, filter with the filename. But a handle is merely just an index for an array in kernel code, it doesn't provide any additional info

Comment: the `WriteFile` never return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. then you need zero init `hEvent` inside `OVERLAPPED` or assign valid value to it. and we always can use offset inside `OVERLAPPED`

Comment: Thank you @RbMm, this works indeed, but only if I put Offset and OffsetHigh to 0xFFFFFFFF. If I use a different value, then I again get the same error. So I can only append to the file. If I want to write to a specific offset, it does't work. So can I assume the handle has been created without the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag ?

Comment: no, you mistake assume. you can **always** use offset in `OVERLAPPED`. you not init `hEvent` in `OVERLAPPED` - this is error. and `WriteFile` not return 183. you bad check

Comment: Can you do ReOpenFile to add the OVERLAPPED attribute?

Comment: @stark - for what (and what is this ?) *OVERLAPPED attribute* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for write to a specific offset via [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) we need set this offset inside [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped):

> This offset is specified by setting the **Offset** and **OffsetHigh**
>   members of the [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped) structure.

this is very common mistake assume that we can use [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped) only with asynchronous file handle (If `hFile` is opened with **`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`**). but this not true. we can **always** use pointer to [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped) in [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) as parameter. different only in next - in case asynchronous file handle this is **mandatory** parameter, otherwise **optional**

> **`OVERLAPPED`** structure is required if the hFile parameter was
>   opened with **`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`**, otherwise this parameter **can**
>   be **`NULL`**.

can be but not must be.

another way for set file position - use `SetFilePointer[Ex]` - is absolete, not efficient and pointer to raise contditional - all what do this api - set `CurrentByteOffset` inside [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. then in `WriteFile` if we not provide explicit offset via `OVERLAPPED` - implicit offset `FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset` used. do this (several additional calls to kernel which not need really) - very not efficient compare explicit file offset on `OVERLAPPED` (and when sombody else use file in concurrent - this offset can be changed between `SetFilePointer[Ex]` and `WriteFile` or `ReadFile` calls)
also [*The old DOS SetFilePointer API is an anachronism.  One should specify the file offset in the overlapped structure even for synchronous I/O.*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/winserverperformance/2008/06/25/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-iii-2/)

but when we use [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped) structure - we **must** initialize it `hEvent` member to 0 or to valid event handle with `SYNCHRONIZE|EVENT_MODIFY_STATE` access rigths(and this event must be **unique** per I/O request - not used in concurrent in another I/O request, until this not finished).

so your current code, when you not intialize `hEvent` inside `_OVERLAPPED offset;` by fact is *UB*. some time it can work ok, if `hEvent` will be random 0. otherwice you can got next status errors:
`STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` (the random value inside `hEvent` not valid handle at all), `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH` (handle is valid but not event), `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` (handle not have `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE`)

but i sure that `WriteFile` not return to you error `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. only `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION` is converted to this error and i not view any place where, how `NtWriteFile` can return such status. i absolute sure that you not got this error, but another. and always good call `RtlGetLastNtStatus();` instead (or with) `GetLastError()` for better diagnostic in this case

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation ! However, I do initialize hEvent to NULL. So I understand that the error I'm getting (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) is NOT relevant in the case of WriteFile, but the fact is that WriteFile returns NULL..

Comment: Also, I can't find the implementation of RtlGetLastNtStatus().

Comment: Sooo, it appears the final reason the WriteFile failed was that I was writting at an offset just a little > the size of the file... -_- Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @Bonjour123 - i absolute sure that you not get `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` but another error. this say that exist error in how you check errors. * I do initialize hEvent to NULL* - this not visiblefrom your code. *implementation of RtlGetLastNtStatus()* - declare this api like `GetLastError()` - both have the same signature and add *ntdll[p].lib*

Comment: Yes, I know that I was not really getting ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, but as it was the one that was returned... Ok, thank you for the tip. * this not visiblefrom your code* yes, I've just mentioned it in my comment under the question. Should I edit it (the question)?

Comment: @Bonjour123- *Yes, I know that I was not really getting ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, but as it was the one that was returned* - i not understand this. you need call `RtlGetLastNtStatus();GetLastError()` **just** after `WriteFile` fail. i absolute sure that you got another error code and `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` is very confuse here. if you have another real code, where you init hEvent to NULL - of course edit question for show  your actual code